# Lodash functions are "type" sensitives

Tags: lodash

I've been using the last version of `lodash` since quite of time and I like it. I have one question though.

I noticed `lodash` functions are "types" sensitives

`_.find(users, {'age': 1});` will not work well if `1` is `"1"`

`_.filter(users, {'age': "36"});` will not work if `"36"` is `36`

#### Question

Is there a way to make `lodash` able to `filter` or `find` objects without taking account the type?

`_.find(users, {'age': 1})` would then return all objects whose `age` is a `string` or a `number` equals to `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of its comparison is with `===` when you are passing an condition, however you can always pass a callback for your kind of checking:

for your purpose:

`_.filter(users, function(user){return user.age==36})`;

It is a plain and simple way of finding even in Native JavaScript, however if you really want to use the benefit of not writing a callback code every time you have a object literal as query data, you can function which will convert a object to it's corresponding callback.

```
function convertToFilterCallback(obj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return function(each) {
        for (var idx = 0; idx < keys.length; idx++) {
            var key = keys[idx];
            if (obj[key] != each[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and then use it like,

```
_.filter(users, convertToFilterCallback({..<your object literal>..}));
```

However, if you are doing so, you can use the native `find` of `filter` method, and specifically not an advantage over lodash.